# Angualar 8.5x with ng install/yarn install throwing error with node-sass and nodev18.x version

Tags: angular, installation

npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (/home/jenkins/workspace/sample-ui_release/node_modules/which/which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (/home/jenkins/workspace/sample-ui_release/node_modules/which/which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (/home/jenkins/workspace/sample-ui_release/node_modules/which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /home/jenkins/workspace/sample-ui_release/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /home/jenkins/workspace/sample-ui_release/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /home/jenkins/workspace/sample-ui_release/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:210:21)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed  python2 Error: not found: python2
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (/home/jenkins/workspace/sample-ui_release/node_modules/which/which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (/home/jenkins/workspace/sample-ui_release/node_moduleswhich/which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (/home/jenkins/workspace/sample-ui_release/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /home/jenkins/workspace/sample-ui_release/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /home/jenkins/workspace/sample-ui_release/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /home/jenkins/workspace/sample-ui_release/node_modulesisexe/mode.js:8:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:210:21) {
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed }
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` succeeded python /var/cfengine/bin/python
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: /var/cfengine/bin/python -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack   File "", line 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack                                ^
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: invalid syntax
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:419:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:514:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1091:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:302:5)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Linux 4.18.0-147.57.1.el8_1.x86_64
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/home/jenkins/workspace/sample-ui_release/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /home/jenkins/workspace/sample-ui_release/node_modules/node_modules/node-sass
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v18.17.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 1
npm verb exit 1

Comment: Angular 8 only supports up to node 10.